# Как отнять час от времени полученного как аргумент в shell скрипте?

Tags: парсер, дата, shell, время, datetime

**Моя задача:** На входе я получаю дату со временем в виде "20170101 14:00:00". Мне нужно отнять час и сохранит в переменную для дальнешего использования.

**Что я сделал:** После нескольких часов гугла и форумов я разобрался с некоторыми основами скриптов в shell. Вчитался в несколько статей про date. Но к сожалению скрипт делает не то что я от него ожидаю.

Скрипт распознает дату и форматирует вправильный вид. Но очень не предсказуемо ведет себя "-1hour". Я получаю правильную дату при "+3hours" и пока перенял это для себя в скрипт. Могут ли возникнуть какие-то непредвиденные результаты в будущем? Это связанно каким-оибо образом с часовыми поясами?

**Вопрос:** Почему "-" прибавляет время, а "+" отнимает? И почему вдруг время начинает исчисляться от "16:00:00" при вводе "14:00:00"?
Буду очень признателен подскаскам или ссылкам где я могу учулшить свои знания в shell скриптах.

```
DATE="20170101 14:00:00"
dat2=$(date -d "$DATE" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
ECHO $dat2
ECHO

date -d "$DATE +0hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
date -d "$DATE +1hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
date -d "$DATE +2hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
date -d "$DATE +3hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
date -d "$DATE +4hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
ECHO
date -d "$DATE -1hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
date -d "$DATE -2hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
date -d "$DATE -3hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S
```

output:

```
20170101 140000

20170101 160000
20170101 150000
20170101 140000
20170101 130000
20170101 120000

20170101 170000
20170101 180000
20170101 190000
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934394/subtract-1-hour-from-date-in-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU date понимает формат `x hour ago`

```
date -d '2017-01-01 15:22:00 2 hour ago' "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
01/01/2017 13:22:00
```

Или ближе к Вашему:

```
date -d '20170101 15:22:00 1 hour ago' "+%Y%m%d %H%M%S"
20170101 142200
date -d '20170101 15:22:00 2 hour ago' "+%Y%m%d %H%M%S"
20170101 132200
```

Answer (score 1):

строкой вида `20170101 14:00:00 +x hour` вы, вероятно, «сбиваете с толку» заложенный в программе *gnu/date* [алгоритм](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats), который пытается разобраться, основываясь на стандарте [iso 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), системном часовом поясе и собственных дополнениях типа `x hour [ago]`, что же именно вы имеете в виду.

---

чтобы дать алгоритму больше однозначности, лучше применять дополнения именно в том виде, как они описаны в справке:

- `дата время 1 hour` — «плюс один час к указанному времени»
- `дата время 1 hour ago` — «минус один час от указанного времени»

---

но если всё-таки по каким-то причинам требуется указывать не `1 hour [ago]`, а `+1 hour`/`-1 hour`, то дайте алгоритму «подсказку» — поместите эту строку **до** даты:

- `-1 hour дата время`
- `+1 hour дата время`

---

p.s. на конкретную цифру часов, выдаваемую программой для строки вида `20170101 14:00:00 +x hour`, оказывает влияние и выбранный в системе часовой пояс (или перекрывающее его значение переменной окружения `TZ`). у меня получилось повторить вашу цифру при `TZ=Europe/Paris` (`UTC+1`):

```
$ TZ=Europe/Paris date -d "20170101 14:00:00 +0hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
20170101 160000
```

при `TZ` же, равном, например, `Europe/Moscow`, цифра будет совсем иная:

```
$ TZ=Europe/Moscow date -d "20170101 14:00:00 +0hour" +'%Y%m%d %H%M%S'
20170101 180000
```